What was the real need of electrostatic field energy? I need resources to build up on the history of electromagnetism
Who discovered electrostatic field energy? What was the need or the application? I need a thorough resource to understand the development of electromagnetism.

What do you mean by "electrostatic field energy"? The potential energy of a charge in electrostatic field or the energy of the field itself?

A long-standing classic are the 3 volumes of A History of the Theories of Aether and Electricity by Edmund Taylor Whittaker, which is freely available on the internet in several places. However, depending on your background knowledge (which you should give some information about), other more accessible papers and books might be more appropriate.

@Conifold I initially meant the energy of the field itself. but I'd love to know more on both schemes. Any of it would be appreciated.

@DaveLRenfro I'm still in the last year of high school. So any resources that you find good enough would be able to help, please suggest.

Related: Is there a concise but detailed history of electricity?

Half baked answer: look for Weber, Helmholz and Carl Neumann. The three discussed the nature of energy in electrodynamics. Heated debate.
